# replicate function in R returns NULL

Tags: r, replicate

I am confused about the output from the replicate function in R, I am trying to use it in two different ways, that (in my mind) should give a matrix as output!

so, if I use

```
replicate(5, seq(1,5,1))
```

I get a matrix 5x5

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

..and that's ok, I get that...

but, if I instead use:

```
replicate(5, for(i in 1:5){print(i)})
```

I get the following:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
```

can anyone explain me why does this happen?
thanks :)

Comment: Your expression returns the value NULL. It also, as a side effect, prints values to the console. But those are distinct actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mrip says a for-loop returns NULL so you need to assign to an object within the loop, and return that object to `replicate` so it can be output. However, mrip's code still results in NULLs from each iteration of the `replicate` evaluation.

You also need to assign the output of `replicate` to a name, so it doesn't just evaporate, er, get garbage collected. That means you need to add the `d` as a separate statement so that the evaluation of the whole expression inside the curley-braces will return 'something' rather than NULL.

```
d <- numeric(5); res <- replicate(5, { 
                            for(i in 1:5){d[i] <- print(i)} ; d}
                                  )
[1] 1
[1] 2

snipped
[1] 4
[1] 5
> res
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the object. if I get it right, you assigned to `res` the `replicate` function, then the `for` loop assigns the output that has to be printed out to `d[i]` and then you visualize `d` that should be replicated 5 times, that's why you get the matrix...correct?

Comment: Basically yes, but I prefer to think about nested function calls "from the inside out" so I would have reversed that sequence you constructed.

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop returns `NULL`.  So in the second case, the `replicate` function is executing `for(i in 1:5){print(i)}` five times, which is why you see all those numbers printed out.

Then it is putting the return values in a list, so the return value of the `replicate` call is a list of five `NULL`s, which gets printed out.  Executing

```
x<-replicate(5, for(i in 1:5){print(i)})
x
```

should clarify.

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes, I did actually try that before and noticed that `x` returns `NULL` but I am confused about why it does that. is that because `for` returns a list first (5 times 1-->5) and then it doesn't run so that the `replicate` has 5 `NULLs`?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is giving a list back, while the `seq()` call is giving a vector back. This should give you the same as the `seq()` using a for loop

```
foo <- function(){
  b = list()
  for(i in 1:5) b[i] <- i
  do.call(c, b)
}

replicate(5, foo())
```

Comment: the function you wrote does work, looks like you used the `b[i] <- i` assignment similar to what @DWin did. I have one question tho, sorry if it's trivial, in the `do.call(c, b)`, I get what `b` is, but how about `c`?

Comment: c is just the function `c`, see `?c`. it combines values into a vector or list